# Scanning the folders in the jar's current path

Tags: java, jar, directory

I'm trying to make a java mini program for exporting the folder names in a given directory into a .txt file. Besides that I want it to use the current directory of the jar in case that the user doesnt specify the directory path, but I cant get that "current path" to work! I'd appreciate any help you can give me, here's what I have so fa: 
`

```
package checker;
import java.io.*;
public class Checker
{
    public boolean chequee(String r){
        boolean funciono=false;
        File folder = new File(".");
        System.out.println(folder.getAbsolutePath());
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        String res="";

        try{
            String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            File textFile = new File(userHomeFolder, "mytext.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile));

            res=r;
            if(res!=""){
                folder = new File(res);
                listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            }



            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {      
                if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                    out.append(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    out.newLine();
                }

                funciono = true;
            }


            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }


        return funciono;
    }

}
```

Comment: `File folder = new File(".");` should work.  What about it isn't working?

Comment: doesnt return any folder names, but if the use types the path manually it works like a charm